How can I set the display environment variable on a Raspberry Pi at boot?
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with a 1280x800 display and no keyboard or mouse. I ssh into it remotely over WiFi and am coding it to display images, ultimately on its own without my ssh into it. I installed feh and am using it in a python script to display an image:
import subprocess
image = subprocess.Popen(["feh", "--hide-pointer", "-x", "-q", "-B", "black", "-g", "1280x800", "./test.jpg"])

I can get this code to work if I type into the command line
export DISPLAY=:0.0

beforehand. However, I would like to have that automatically at boot so that I can run the python code at boot as well and have it run autonomously. I tried putting that line into /etc/profile, but it didn't work.
Sorry for my operating system naïveté--it's a real weakness. And thanks in advance for any help.

The folks over at [raspberrypi.se] can probably answer this immediately.

Have you tried to set the DISPLAY variable at the same time your script is called? Let's say your python script is at /home/dribbler/display_images.py. Assuming you're using Python 3 at /usr/bin/python3, you could try calling it this way: DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/python3 /home/dribbler/display_images.py.

As a suggestion - in addition to my previous comment -, I would add in this case a shebang to the script to remove the need to run it by calling the python command explicitly. For instance: #!/usr/bin/env python3.

I agree with @TangentiallyPerpendicular, the question is better suited for the Raspberry Pi stack exchange, although we might still be able to help you here.

@NiltonMoura thanks super, I did. See my response to the proposed answer below. The launcher.sh script works from ssh, just not on boot in any way that I can find so far.

I finally got this to work. I used feh to display images. You should install feh with
sudo apt-get install feh 

The python program to run is (obviously replace /home/craign with your own location):
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess
import time

# Set the HOME environment variable
os.environ['HOME'] = '/home/craign'  # Replace with the correct home directory

# Set the DISPLAY environment variable
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'

# Run xhost to allow X server access (you might need to install xhost: sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils)
subprocess.run(['xhost', '+local:'], check=True)

# Display the image
image = subprocess.run(["feh", "--hide-pointer", "-x", "-q", "-F", "-B", "black", "-g", "1280x800", "/home/craign/image.jpg"])

To run the program at boot:
sudo nano /etc/rc.local

Add this line before the exit 0 at the end of the file:
python3 /home/craign/main.py &

Of course make sure everything is executable.

There are a few ways you can do this I will list the one that worked best for me:
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/sudo
#And add this line
session optional pam_xauth.so

This is the ultimate solution to the GUI from ssh problem. This helps while debugging using ssh .
And for automating any python code with GUI to run on boot. (Replace "main.py" with your file name. Also change the directory name based on your username.)
sudo nano launcher.sh

Add the following lines to this file
#!/bin/sh

#launcher.sh

#navigate to home directory, then to this directory, then execute python script, then back home

cd /

cd home/pi4

export DISPLAY=:0;sudo python3 main.py &

Then, to make this execute on boot, do the following:
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

#Add the followng line
 ./launcher.sh

Reboot and check if this works.
Incase you need to run this code through ssh while testing and you are getting the cannot use "sudo" error, use the following:
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev

For more information go through this page I found:
https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/
I hope this helps.

Thanks super for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. launcher.sh works from a ssh as expected, but I cant get it to run on boot. On that instructables page is explained how to set up a crontab to do it , but a root crontab and a user crontab both log the error "feh ERROR: Can't open X display. It is running, yeah?". It's just not finding the display even with that export DISPLAY in launcher.sh. Any ideas?
